# How to Compute the Torsion and Curvature of a Parametric Curve

Tags: differential-geometry, computational-geometry, curves

So I have a parametric curve $\bf{r}=${$x(n),y(n),z(n)$} such that the functions $x(n)$, $y(n)$ and $z(n)$ are polynomials of $4$-th degree. I have several of these curves, and I want to calculate the torsion $\tau(n)$ and the curvature $\kappa(n)$ at a particular point $n_0$ in each of these curves.

So what I am doing is, I am defining the vectors ${\bf r^{(m)}} =\lbrace \frac{d^mx}{dn^m},\frac{d^my}{dn^m},\frac{d^mz}{dn^m} \rbrace$ and I am calculating these things according to the formulae I saw in Wolfram World both for [Torsion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Torsion.html) as well as [Curvature](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Curvature.html).

$\tau(n)= \frac{[\bf{r}^{(1)} \bf{r}^{(2)} \bf{r}^{(3)}]}{|\bf{r}^{(1)} \times \bf{r}^{(2)}|^2}$

and

$\kappa(n)= \frac{|\bf{r}^{(1)} \times \bf{r}^{(2)}|}{|\bf{r}^{(1)}|^3}$

Where $[\bf{r}^{(1)} \bf{r}^{(2)} \bf{r}^{(3)}]$ is the [Scalar Triple Product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ScalarTripleProduct.html). and $| \bf v |$ denotes the norm of $\bf v$.

So I made the calculations but some numbers are just too weird. There are reasonable curves with $\tau(n_0) \approx 1000$. Nothing in the curves would suggest such a strange number, but then again, I'm a newbie here so the first thing I thought was that I had done something wrong along the way and that the computation is screwed up.

I verified the reference again but it seems like everything is in place, I think I'm missing something pretty basic here. Is that a typical value for Torsion in any known case? Can someone point up the mistake in that? Are the formulae wrong?

At least if these are right I can focus all my attentions to implementation mistakes or numerical instabilities.

[EDIT]

Examples of curves where the magnitude of the torsion $|\tau|$ is around the thousands for $n_0=4$. The curves are represented in matrices such that the first line of each matrix represents the polynomial coefficients for $x$, the second for $y$ and the third for $z$.

---

---

Curve 1, $\tau(4) = -2 025.22815027$

\begin{matrix}
0.147791666667 & -1.30558333333 & 3.36670833333 & -2.05691666667 & 1.21 & \\
0.046 & -0.2195 & 0.1335 & -0.406 & -0.884 & \\
-0.11225 & 0.945333333333 & -2.48525 & 2.90216666667 & 4.102 & \\
\end{matrix}

---

Curve 2, $\tau(4)=-32705.0075194$

\begin{matrix}
0.18625 & -1.48266666667 & 3.62875 & -2.18033333333 & 1.21 & \\
-0.0775833333333 & 0.618166666667 & -1.51441666667 & 0.527833333333 & -0.884 & \\
-0.168583333333 & 1.34033333333 & -3.27591666667 & 3.35416666667 & 4.102 &
\end{matrix}

---

Curve 3, $\tau(4)=-3341.5324268$

\begin{matrix}
0.154625 & -1.36408333333 & 3.494375 & -2.13291666667 & 1.21 & \\
0.08 & -0.492 & 0.713 & -0.747 & -0.884 & \\
-0.0382916666667 & 0.399583333333 & -1.36570833333 & 2.25441666667 & 4.102 &
\end{matrix}

---

Curve 4, $\tau(4)=-1026.39066614$

\begin{matrix}
0.146125 & -1.29758333333 & 3.379875 & -2.13241666667 & 1.21 & \\
0.0777916666667 & -0.58175 & 1.31270833333 & -1.95175 & -0.884 & \\
0.145291666667 & -1.13441666667 & 2.82470833333 & -2.51958333333 & 4.102 &
\end{matrix}

Comment: What is a "reasonable" curve to you? What did you try this on?

Comment: Well, the curves don't intersect themselves, and all of them are finite segments of a smooth polynomial curve, as stated above. But in fact I have no idea what kind of curve would have a $+1000$ of torsion, I see no reason why should the numerator be so large and/or the denominator be so small in the definition of $\tau$. My main concern though is if the definitions are correct.

Comment: Can you please give the equation of the curves that you are trying?! I would like to verify your claims.

Comment: There are A LOT of them, but I am sending some of those where the torsion for $n_0=4$ is absurd. Like, around the thousands or minus thousands.

Comment: $0.147791666667 -1.30558333333 3.36670833333 -2.05691666667 1.21
0.046 -0.2195 0.1335 -0.406 -0.884
-0.11225 0.945333333333 -2.48525 2.90216666667 4.102
$

Comment: @VictorLiu, I edited the original post to put the coefficients there along with the torsion values I have computed so that you can verify.